# When does a finite group have a lower-dimensional representation than one of its quotients?

Tags: finite-groups, characters

The minimal dimension of a nontrivial representation of a central extension of a group $G$ can be smaller than the minimal dimension of a nontrivial representation of $G$.  What about non-central extensions?  More precisely:

Suppose a finite group $G$ has no nontrivial central extensions, i.e. the Schur multiplier of $G$ is trivial.  Let $\tilde{G} \to G$ be a finite nontrivial extension of $G$, but of course not a central one.

Let $d$ be the smallest dimension of a nontrivial representation of $G$.  Is the dimension of a nontrivial representation of $\tilde{G}$ necessarily greater than or equal to $d$?

Comment: What is meant by a "nontrivial extension"? Presumably this excludes direct products, but how about semidirect products? The regular wreath product of an abelian group by G is an extension that has a nontrivial representation of degree 1.